# Tables or divs for responsive checkout process?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, e-commerce, shopping-cart, fluid

I am working on a checkout process for e-commerce, 
and the website should be fully responsive. 
I use Bootstrap as a baseline and tables are always a pain for the mobile view.

I have looked at a lot of different solutions regarding tables, and they dont really consider elements such as form elements ( quantities, color selectors, delete, add to cart buttons )

There are lots of subtle variations of tables in the website and wanted to see what others thought before developing something.

**My question is..**

Is it best to use tables or build them using other elements,
considering semantics, maintaining, usability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tables should only be used for rendering tabular data.

Their inclusion will slow down the layout process in many browsers, causing a less responsive UI experience.

Comment: Hi Eric, Yes for sure only use tables for tabular data. 
But isn't the users "cart", "wishlist" tabular data ??

So would it be best practice for a responsive website to break down the table or to ditch the table for lets say a div instead ??

Comment: Tabular data is *data* that should be organized into rows and columns (think of an Excel spread sheet).  Don't use tables just because the *layout* is organized into rows and columns.  There are real downsides (e.g. slower page rendering) to doing that.

Comment: Ah ok, Thanks Eric. really cleared that up for me :) 
appreciate it